# How to force javascript not to make callback functions parallel?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, mongoose

I'm building a twitter clone using Node.js and MongoDB with mongoose. My `Tweet` model has `body`, `user` and `created` fields where `user` is the id of the user who has created the tweet. Now I'm building the API. I want when I make a GET request to receive a list of all the tweets (`/api/tweets/`) but except the `user` field (which returns only the id of the user) I want to get the whole user object so that I can display information about the tweet owner in my front-end part. I ended up with the following code.

```
exports.all = function (req, res, next) {
  Tweet.find({}, function (err, tweets) {
    if (err) return res.json(400, err);

    var response = [];
    tweets.forEach(function (element, index, array) {
      var tweet = {};
      tweet._id = element._id;
      tweet.created = element.created;
      tweet.body = element.body;
      User.findById(element.user, function (err, user) { // <- This line
        if (err) return res.json(400, err);

        tweet.user = user;
      });

      response.push(tweet);
    });

    return res.json(response);
  });
};
```

It works perfectly except that it doesn't add the user info. The problem is in the line I have marked. When javascript comes to that line, it tries to make it "parallel" and continues with the code without executing the callback function. But then it pushes the `tweet` object that doesn't have yet user info. How can I fix this?

Comment: An asynchronous API cannot be made synchronous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to want to use the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) library. It will make your life much easier.

```
// inside `Tweet.find`
async.each(tweets, function(done) {
    // do stuff to tweets
    User.findById(element.user, function(err, user){
        if (err) return done(err);
        // do stuff with user
        done();
    });
}, function(err) {
   // called when done
   res.json(response);
});
```

Comment: I would highly recommend this route also. Using Async is just needed in some cases without chaining a load of callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `res.json` sends the response so it doesn't matter that `findById` is being called.  You need to call `res.json` once everything is done.

You can do this in several ways, but the easiest one with your existing code is to just keep a counter:

```
var tweetCount = 0;

tweets.forEach(/* snip */) {
    User.findById(element.user, function (err, user) {
        tweet.user = user;
        tweetCount++;
        response.push(tweet);

        if (tweetCount == tweets.length) {
            res.json(response);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ***Q*** promise library to ***sync***. It is simple and easy to use.

Response will only be send when whole promise chain is compeleted

```
var result = Q();
tweets.forEach(function (tweet, i) {
     result = result.then(function () {
         // do your stuff
     }

result.then(function () {
    res.json(response);  //successfully completed
});
```